# Quickblox block / ban contact like Facebook

Tags: ios, chat, contacts, quickblox

I have been developing a chat application using **Quickblox** framework.
I have been reading and testing many official sample projects (including **Q-municate**) but i do not find a way to block / ban user.
Is there a method for achieving this functionality ? Do i need to implement Custom Objects ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Objects for now. For example, create a class and store IDs of blocked users there. And then develop appropriate logic on the client side.

QuickBlox is going to release 'true' block list soon, also it will be available within Q-municate project

Comment: I am following your repository at Bitbucket because i am developing an IM application. I noticed that the Quickblox framework used in Q-municate is different from the one that is released on Quickblox website. Is it safe to use it ?